# How to copy columns from Database A to Database B in phpMyAdmin

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

I would like to copy some columns from Table "SourceTable" in Database "SourceDB" to a Table "DestinationTable" in Database "DestinationDB" with an SQL script in phpMyAdmin 3.5.3. My SQL-Script is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO `DestinationDB..DestinationTable` (
    `ID`, 
    `Name`
    )
SELECT 
    `id`, 
    `name`
FROM `SourceTable..SourceTable`
```

- If I run it at localhost (no database selected) I get the error:
  "#1046 - No database selected"
- If I run it at localhost >> DestinationDB, I get:
  "#1146 - Table 'DestinationDB.DestinationDB..DestinationTable' doesn't exist"
  or if I remove the "DestinationDB.." in the SQL-Script:
  "#1146 - Table 'DestinationDB.SourceTable..SourceTable' doesn't exist"

So the part before the .. is not recognised as the name of the Database. Where is my error or is there a different way to achieve the data transfer?

Thanks in advance for your help.
Thali

Comment: Single . (Dot) is enough. no need two Dots. Remove one . (Dot) and try scenario 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO DestinationDB.DestinationTable ( ID, Name)
(SELECT id, name FROM SourceTable.SourceTable)
```

Note:

1. Two Dots(..) can't be used here. single Dot is enough for Map the Database.
   Use `DestinationDB`.`DestinationTable`

Comment: Thanks Joker and Swapnil for your answers, who helped but didn't lead to full success.
I removed the two dots(..) and only used one(.), but the result is the same: PhpMyAdmin 3.5.3. always add the active database infront of the given Database `ActiveDB.DestinationDB.DestinationTable`.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also

Select(id,name) into DestinationDB.DestinationTable(ID,Name) from SourceDB.SourceTable